# Removing wpautop (p tags are still present)

Tags: wordpress

I would like to understand how to properly remove wpautop.

**My code:**

```
function n_custom_html($atts, $content = null){    
    /**
     * [n-custom-html]<script>alert("hi");</script>[n-custom-html]
     */    

    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
    $result = strval($content);
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );

    return $result;
}
```

Then I try to use it:

```
[n-custom-html]<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($){ //  Disable scrolling down when pressing spacebar in Wordpress.
    window.onkeydown = function(e) { return !(e.keyCode == 32); };
});

document.body.onkeyup = function(e){ // Pause all countdown timers when spacebar is pressed.
    if(e.keyCode == 32){ // Spacebar pressed.
        alert("hi");
    }

}</script>
[n-custom-html]
```

It has not helped (see the screenshot). What can I try next?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `shortcode_unautop`, more here:  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_unautop/

Comment: Yes, I tried. But also failed.